# Chat room link can't be renamed

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks, so-engine

We tried to link the http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage proposal in the corresponding chat room topic using the traditional :

```
[French Language and Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage)
```

But it does not work. Could we have this feature?

#### Edit:

If it's by design, I'm interested in a workaround to create named link in chat room topics. It would avoid having long lines of useless text.

Comment: Nope, no Markdown in the room topic is indeed by design, so you should turn it into a feature request :)

Comment: Well markdown is not a requirement, but having a way to turn links into text would be nice.